# Use of google map in a 2 column responsive layout

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to insert a map into the column 2 and the whole site should be responsive. I know my code is poorly written, this is my first time with such thing, and after a day of searching for a solution, I am really desperate now.

HTML

```
<div class="section group">
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_2">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col {
display: block;
float:left;
margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
.span_2_of_2 {
width: 100%;
}
.span_1_of_2 {
width: 49.2%;
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.col { 
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0%;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.span_2_of_2, .span_1_of_2, #map-canvas { width: 100%; }
}
```

Javascript code in the links

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doZBGb
If the link for codepen not working:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/161951ccd66d110aed83

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: this is really easy to solve,  go to your developer mode,  check what element control the top most width add 100% width to the desired element.  add !important if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm...

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ34s/26/)**.

```
var map;
var coordinates;

function placeMarker(location) {
    //marker will only exist inside this function
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        draggable: true
    });
}

function initialize() {

    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(46.910246, 18.048979);
    var options = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (evt) {
        placeMarker(evt.latLng);
        coordinates = Array(evt.latLng + ';');
    });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();

    $('input[name="get-coordinates"]').click(function() {
        console.log(coordinates);
    });
});
```

**and all you gotta do is:**

```
#map { // use this selector to make responsive
    width: 450px; // change this to %
    height: 400px; // and or call between @media 
}
```

*...and that's it!*